# pyside6 (6.6.1): QTableView from pyside6-designer how to service mouse presses?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyside6

I have created a TableView using `pyside6-designer`. I want to handle mouse events for custom behavior from my code.

As the class is generated from designer, it's not clear how I can respond to mouse events, and for that matter keyboard events.

For example, for right mouse click on a row I want to popup a context menu.

Comment: You can use widget-promotion in qt-designer and then reimplement the relevant event-handlers in a custom subclass; or install an event-filter.

Comment: Do these answer your question? [Easiest way to subclass a widget in Python for use with Qt Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60311219/) [Create different context menus on several QTableViews](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60922666)

Comment: @ekhumoro - Thanks, that set me in the right direction

Comment: @musicamante - Yes, it does now (once I dug deeper from `ekhumoro` comment) and no need to monkeypatch